# If we think of infinity as a number, how does it affect the compactness/completeness of a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, infinity, complete-spaces

I was recently reviewing some notes regarding compactness, in which the sequential definition is given i.e. "$A$ is compact if any sequence in $A$ has a subsequence which converges to a limit in $A$. So in this instance we are only concerned with sequences in $A$ which actually converge.

I can recall one of my analysis lectures where someone mentioned thinking of infinity as a point on the real line (for some unrelated topic), and this got me wondering how compactness/completeness would be effected if we decided to include infinity in the reals as if it was a number (or for any metric space).

From what I've determined, all of the sequences which diverge to infinity are now considered convergent, and so the previously compact sets are now no longer compact since they do not include the limits of every convergent sequence, and the only compact space could be the whole space itself correct? (Unless we can place infinity in some arbitrary point not on the boundary).

Also, In trying to work with this idea, I am struggling to come to terms with how this would effect Cauchy sequences. Given that the previously "divergent" sequences now converge, if our triangle inequality still holds wouldn't they now be Cauchy since they get closer to infinity as they grow larger? Shouldn't we have to change our notion of distance in this new space to avoid a contradiction?

Comment: A good way to think about this is that $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$, and $\pm \infty$ are like $0$ and $1$. If you count $\pm \infty$ as a single point, you get a space homeomorphic to a circle. If you count them as separate points, you get a space homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. And if you only add one of them, you get $(0,1]$ or $[0,1)$. However, this operation only works if you extend $\mathbb{R}$ as a *topological* space. You can't extend it sensibly while keeping the same distance. Whether a sequence is Cauchy has to do with the choice of distance, not just the topology.

Comment: "so the previously compact sets are now no longer compact since they do not include the limits of every sequence" -- absolutely not.

Comment: @David Can you please elaborate on how infinity as a single point is homeomorphic to a circle?

Comment: @symplectomorphic are you just reiterating my remark or disagreeing with it?

Comment: Define a mapping between the unit circle $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$ by stereographic projection. That is, to every real number $x$, associate the intersection of $C$ with the line from $N = (0,1)$ to $(x,0)$ (besides $N$ itself). This defines a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $C - \{N\}$. When $\pm \infty$ is considered a single point, $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ has the topology of $C$, with $\infty$ corresponding to $N$.

Comment: I think symplectomorphic means that sets that were originally compact stay compact.

Comment: How can it stay compact if it didn't include infinity to begin with?

Comment: How can what stay compact? For example, $[-1,1]$ stays compact after $\pm \infty$ are added.

Comment: @ElChapo: the sentence I quoted is obviously false because whether a set includes "the limits of every sequence" has nothing to do with compactness.

Comment: whoops let me edit that statement.

Comment: Are you familiar with topological spaces, or only metric spaces?

Comment: I've had a small introduction to the topology of a metric space, but not topological spaces in general.

Comment: It is quite difficult to talk about these questions in the context of metric spaces. To extend $\mathbb{R}$ in this way, you also need to change the distances between real numbers themselves. So adjoining points like this is not a natural operation when $\mathbb{R}$ is considered as a metric space.